# Matlab: Increment of matrix values with indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, increment

I have a vector of indices and want to increase values in matrix in every index. For example:

```
    ind = [1 2 2 5];
    m = zeros(3);
    m(ind) = m(ind) + 1;
```

The result is as follow:

```
    m = [1 0 0
         1 1 0
         0 0 0]
```

But I need the results to be

```
    m = [1 0 0
         2 1 0
         0 0 0]
```

The time complexity is very important to me, and I can't use for. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that sometimes, a vectorized solution is not faster than a for loop, as MATLAB has greatly optimised for loops in the recent versions

Comment: @AnderBiguri Even in this case?

Comment: The best way of knowing is triying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a sorted array of indices, we can have a play of [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
out = zeros(M,N);  % Output array of size(M,N)
df = diff([0,ind,ind(end)+1]);
put_idx = diff(find(df)); % gets count of dups
out(ind(df(1:end-1)~=0)) = put_idx;
```

The basic idea being we count the duplicates along the length with `diff`. Those counts are the values to be assigned into the zeros array. The indices at which those values are to be assigned are simply the unique indices, which could be found out by looking for the start of each group of duplicate indices.

### Benchmarking

Script to create sorted indices array (`create_data.m`) -

```
function ind = create_data(M,N, num_unq_ind, max_repeats)

unq_ind = unique(randi([1,M*N],1,num_unq_ind));
num_repeats = randi(max_repeats, [1,numel(unq_ind)]);
ind = repelem(unq_ind, num_repeats);
```

Benchmarking script (`bench1.m`) to test out various scenarios -

```
clear all; close all;

M = 5000; % Array size
N = 5000;

% Input params and setup input indices array (edited for various runs)
num_unq_ind = 100000;
max_repeats = 100;
ind = create_data(M,N, num_unq_ind, max_repeats);

num_iter = 100; % No. of iterations to have reliable benchmarking 
disp('Input params :')
disp(['num_unq_ind = ' int2str(num_unq_ind)])
disp(['max_repeats = ' int2str(max_repeats)])

disp('------------------ Using diff ----------------')
tic
for i=1:num_iter
    out = zeros(M,N);
    df = diff([0,ind,ind(end)+1]);
    put_idx = diff(find(df));
    out(ind(df(1:end-1)~=0)) = put_idx;
end
toc

% Luis's soln
disp('------------------ Using accumaray ----------------')
tic
for i=1:num_iter
    m = reshape(accumarray(ind(:), 1, [N^2 1]), N, N);
end
toc
```

Various scenario runs -

```
>> bench1
Input params :
num_unq_ind = 10000
max_repeats = 10
------------------ Using diff ----------------
Elapsed time is 0.948544 seconds.
------------------ Using accumaray ----------------
Elapsed time is 1.502658 seconds.
>> bench1
Input params :
num_unq_ind = 100000
max_repeats = 10
------------------ Using diff ----------------
Elapsed time is 1.784576 seconds.
------------------ Using accumaray ----------------
Elapsed time is 1.533280 seconds.
>> bench1
Input params :
num_unq_ind = 10000
max_repeats = 100
------------------ Using diff ----------------
Elapsed time is 1.315998 seconds.
------------------ Using accumaray ----------------
Elapsed time is 1.391323 seconds.
>> bench1
Input params :
num_unq_ind = 100000
max_repeats = 100
------------------ Using diff ----------------
Elapsed time is 6.180565 seconds.
------------------ Using accumaray ----------------
Elapsed time is 3.576154 seconds.
```

With less sparsey and more repeats, `accumarray` seems to be doing better.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way. I haven't timed it.

```
ind = [1 2 2 5];
N = 3;
m = full(reshape(sparse(ind, 1, 1, N^2, 1), N, N));
```

Equivalently, you can use

```
ind = [1 2 2 5];
N = 3;
m = reshape(accumarray(ind(:), 1, [N^2 1]), N, N);
```

or its variation (thanks to @beaker)

```
ind = [1 2 2 5];
N = 3;
m = zeros(N);
m(:) = accumarray(ind(:), 1, [N^2 1]);
```

This one is probably slower than the others:

```
ind = [1 2 2 5];
N = 3;
m = zeros(N);
[ii, ~, vv] = find(accumarray(ind(:), 1));
m(ii) = vv;
```

Comment: Fantastic vectorized solution! However, I have the feeling that the first one will certainly take more time than a for loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use [histcounts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)

```
n = 3;
m = reshape(histcounts(ind, [1:n^2 n^2]), n, n);
```